# How to link mongo with node using docker compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker-compose

I'm trying link my node server with my db in Mongo, but doesn't work...

This is my Docker-Compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
      human:
          build:
            context: ./human-app
          container_name: human
          ports:
            - "3001:3001"
      mongodb:
          image: mongo
          container_name: mongodb
          env_file:
            - ./human-app/srcs/.env
          environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=Pepe
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=PepePass
            - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=Pool
          ports:
            - "27017:27017"
          volumes:
            - ./volumes_mongo:/data/db
```

And when i run the command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Everything work correctly but separate, i check the status with the command "docker ps -a" and the result is this:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                      NAMES
9335c5cd4940   mongo                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongodb
2a28635d2caa   human-selection-app_human   "node server"            4 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds   0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp     human
```

If i enter in my container of mongo, and follow the next steps, thats happen:

1- docker exec -it mongodb bash
2- mongo
3- show dbs "result no dbs"

So, i can't link nothing with my node server, probably i need create a network for the 2 services? can anyone help me? thanks.

Extra, this is how i connect from my server to MongoDB:

```
    async _connectDB() {

        //! We create the connection to the database

        const dbUser = process.env.DBUSER;;
        const dbPassword = process.env.DBPASSWORD;
        const dbName = process.env.DBNAME;
        const dbUriLocal = `mongodb://${dbUser}:${dbPassword}@127.0.0.1:27017/${dbName}`;

        
        mongoose.connect(dbUriLocal, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
            .then(() => console.log(clc.cyan('Debug: Database connected successfully')))
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your application is also running inside of a Docker container being in the same network with the MongoDB Service, it means you should use MongoDB's service name as the connection address instead of the localhost IP address.
Change your `dbUriLocal` variable to use the MongoDB Service name (in your case, it is "mongodb" named after the service name in `docker-compose.yml`) as the connection address instead of "127.0.0.1":

```js
const dbUriLocal = `mongodb://${dbUser}:${dbPassword}@mongodb:27017/${dbName}`;
```

See "Networking" in the [Docker Compose File Referrence](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#networks) for more information.

Comment: Still throwing error when i try use the DB from node, this is the error:

```
/human-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:148
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `candidates.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/human-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:148:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

you know why this happen? @Vladyslav

Comment: @Bart, How do you pass `DBUSER`, `DBPASSWORD` and `DBNAME` environment variables to your application? I don't see them in your docker-compose. Maybe you are using tools such as `dotenv`?

Comment: Yes, i check the env variables in the app and was ok, but idk the authentication fail.

Comment: When i saw the log, the app throw me this error :

```
Debug: Server listening on port 3001
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
}
```